# Css dropdown menu z-index issue

Tags: html, css

I have created a menu bar with out bootstrap the problem is that dropdown z-index is not working during dropdown when there is an image below I have given position relative and absolute to both image and menu, can any one help?

**code:**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="nolink">MASTER</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="master_textile.php">TEXTILE</a></li>
          <li><a href="master_nontextile.php">NON-TEXTILE</a></li>
          <li><a href="branch_name_master.php">BRANCH NAME</a></li>
          <li><a href="initial_stock.php">INITIAL STOCK - TEXTILE</a></li>
          <li><a href="initial_stock_non_textile.php">INITIAL STOCK - NON TEXTILE</a></li>
         <li><a href="initial_stock_silk.php">INITIAL STOCK - SILK</a></li>
          <li><a href="customer_details_master.php">CUSTOMER DETAILS</a></li>
          <li><a href="percent.php">PERCENT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nolink">PURCHASE</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="purchase_textile.php">TEXTILE</a></li>
          <li><a href="purchase_silk_textile.php">SILK</a></li>
          <li><a href="purchase_nontextile.php">NON-TEXTILE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
    <li><a class="nolink">RETAIL SALE</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="retail_sales.php">TEXTILE</a></li>
          <li><a href="retail_sales_silk.php">SILK</a></li>
          <li><a href="retailsale_nontextile.php">NON-TEXTILE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
    <li><a class="nolink">WHOLE SALE</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="whole_sales.php">TEXTILE</a></li>
          <li><a href="whole_sales_silk.php">SILK</a></li>
          <li><a href="whole_nontextile.php">NON-TEXTILE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
    <li><a class="nolink">RETURN BILLS</a>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="retail_textile_cancel_bill.php">RETURN BILL - TEXTILE</a></li>
             <li><a href="silk_return_bill.php">RETURN BILL - SILK</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nolink">SUMMARY</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="nolink">BILL SUMMARY</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Summary_textile.php">RS - TEXTILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="summary_nontextile.php">RS - NON-TEXTILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="wholesale_summary_textile.php">WS - TEXTILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="wholesale_summary_nontextile.php">WS - NON-TEXTILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="purchase_summary_textile.php">PU - TEXTILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="purchase_summary_nontextile.php">PU - NON-TEXTILE</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a class="nolink">STOCK BOOK</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="stockbook.php">TEXTILE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="stockbook_silk.php">SILK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="stockbook_nontextile.php">NON-TEXTILE</a></li>
                </ul>
          </li>
            <li><a class="nolink">ALTER</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="paisa_alter.php">PAISA  - ALTER</a></li>
                  <li><a href="summary_date_alter.php">DATE  - ALTER</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nolink">LOAN</a>
        <ul>
             <li class="dropdown_submenu non"><a href="#">TEXTILE</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="loanlist.php">VIEW LOAN LIST</a></li>
                    <li><a href="loan_personal_list.php">PERSONAL LIST</a></li>
                    <li><a href="loancr.php">LOAN CR</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">NON-TEXTILE</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="loan_list_nontex.php">PERSONAL LIST</a></li>
                    <li><a href="loan_cr_nontex.php">LOAN CR</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nolink">REPORT</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">TEXTILE</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="initial_tex_report.php">INITIAL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="closing_tex_report.php">CLOSING</a></li>
                </ul>
          </li>
            <li><a href="#">NON-TEXTILE</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="initial_nontex_report.php">INITIAL</a></li>
                <li><a href="closing_nontex_report.php">CLOSING</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**css:**

```
a {
    color: #3bb3a9;
}
#nav {
    padding: 2px 4px 0;
    line-height: 100%;   
    background:#3bb3a9; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3bb3a9', endColorstr='#3bb3a9'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3bb3a9), to(#3bb3a9)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #3bb3a9,  #3bb3a9); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

    border: solid 1px #329c92;
}
#nav li {
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
/* main level link */
#nav a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding:  4px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1.6em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1.6em;
}
/* main level link hover */
#nav .current > a, #nav li:hover > a {
    background:#329c92; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#329c92', endColorstr='#329c92'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#329c92), to(#329c92)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#329c92, #329c92); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

    color: white;
}
/* sub levels link hover */
#nav ul li:hover a, #nav li:hover li a {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
    background: #329c92 !important; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#329c92', endColorstr='#329c92'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(#329c92), to(#329c92)) !important; /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #329c92,  #329c92) !important; /* for firefox 3.6+ */

    color: white !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
}
/* level 2 list */
#nav ul {
    background: #3bb3a9; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3bb3a9', endColorstr='#3bb3a9'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3bb3a9), to(#3bb3a9)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #3bb3a9,  #3bb3a9); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 185px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27px;
    left: 0;
    border: solid 1px #3bb3a9;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
/* dropdown */
#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav li ul.stayopen {
    display: block !important;
}
#nav li ul.stayopen li a {
    color: white;
}
#nav ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav ul a {
    font-weight: normal;
}
/* level 3+ list */
#nav ul ul {
    left: 181px;
    top: -3px;
}
/* rounded corners for first and last child */
#nav ul li:first-child > a {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 9px;

    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 9px;
}
#nav ul li:last-child > a {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 9px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 9px;
}
/* clearfix */
#nav:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
#nav {
}
html[xmlns] #nav {
    display: block;
}
* html #nav {
    height: 1%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: please try add position:relative;z-index:9999; on #nav

Comment: i had tried not working.

Comment: i have fo wait.und out the answer i will post it

Comment: did you set z-index and position on logo container?

Comment: why you need position: relative; on li tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add zindex for the next level of nav like below.

```
#nav ul
{
 z-index:999 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found out the answer too its working now...

```
#nav li {
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    z-index:1;
}
```

by adding this code in css.